# How to modify the values in one database based on changes in the other database?

Tags: mysql, database, steam

I'm running a gaming server and a gaming forum. Each have their own databases. The game server has a database that tracks all players and their store credits (for in-game cosmetic items). Then the forum database that tracks users, posts and so on.

My goal here is to reward players that post on the forum, by awarding them in-game currency after every forum post they submit. I am trying to improve forum participation with this method.

How can I make it so that every time a user posts, it would tell the gaming server's database to add a set amount of in-game currency to their attached account?

The forum tracks users by their registration ID. The game server tracks users by their account ID.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What database type are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have access or don't wish to add code to your forum installation in order to achieve this, the solution then could be to use triggers for MySQL. You'll need to replace with correct table names etc. as you didn't post your database table-structure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CreditsSync` AFTER UPDATE ON `F`.Posts
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   UPDATE `U`.Users, `F`.Posts SET `U`.Users.credits = `F`.Posts.num WHERE `F`.Posts.userid = `U`.Users.id
END
```

Triggers require MySQL 5.5 or higher, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html for more information.

*EDIT* - Noticed that you wanted to insert into different tables in different databases, in the above SQL F = forum database, and U = user database - you'll need to replace this with the correct targeting for your dbs and tables.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I will look into it. And yes I am ready to modify my forum to achieve this result. Would it be best if I  try to modify the forum or go with the way you posted?

Comment: That depends on what version of MySQL you have, triggers are a great way to solve this - but if you don't have that version available you'll need to add some (PHP?) code to your forum installation. If you found the answer helpful you can accept it and/or vote for it.